# Xcode - search scope to exclude files or path

Tags: ios, xcode

If your project is big and has many localizations, sometimes you find view controllers by searching for text displayed on that view controller's view. But in doing so you get a lot of search results you don't need that can make finding the file you're searching for cumbersome:

[image]

If you're like me and do this a hundred times a day, you want to have a way to omit Localizable files from your searches, for example. How?

Answer (score 30):

1. In the Find Navigator tab, click the current search scope directly underneath the search bar:

[image: where to click under search bar]

2. Click "New Scope..." and give it a name. I picked 'Workspace W/O Localizable":

[image: new search scope configuration]

3. Add a Path condition that 'matches regex'. You can use a negative regex to exclude paths with "Localizable" in it. The regex to use is this: ^((?!Localizable).)*$

That's it! Just click the new search scope under "SEARCH SCOPES" and it will be the new default.

Comment: how to append another path to this regex?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov click on "+" button, this will add another position which can be defined as another Path match regex

Answer (score 4):

Quick tip which is a solution for some. You can easily change this by clicking on a result and hitting "delete." This will remove the result or group of results from the list. It will not affect your code ;)

Comment: Works for sporadic searches, but does not persist. So the unwanted results/groups come back for every consecutive search, and with Localizable.strings files at least you'll have to select/delete a lot of files (they don't group) :/

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip for xCode 9.4. Create a search scope of this to search just the swift files in your project.
[image]

Comment: the question was about excluding of folder, not filtering "swift" files

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov with the search scopes you can exclude as well . justdan0227  +1