# Best way to store large number of files in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, storage

I currently have around 4,000 SVG files in the Project directory of my macOS app.
And Fetching them using the line below, and it's working as expected.
`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "icon1", withExtension: "svg")`

But due to the large number of files I'm having issues such as slow searches in the project directory in XCode.

I'm looking for a better approach to storing these files.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-assets-with-asset-catalogs#).

If the only issue is in Xcode, you can also make the directory a folder reference (drag the folder into Xcode and select "folder references" rather than groups. This will keep Xcode from managing the folder directly. It'll treat the entire folder as one "unit."

If the main issue is searches, you can [create a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066546/xcode-search-scope-to-exclude-files-or-path) that excludes your images.

Comment: Can't access them as SVGs if its in the assets catalog. I've already tried adding reference instead of groups, the items still get listed in search. It's not just search, even the Git commits take a while.

Comment: If you don't need versioning for your SVG files, you can add the directory enclosing them to the `.gitignore` file.